# AutoMapper Entidades ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ddd, automapper, viewmodel

estou com um cenários onde meu contexto retorna uma consulta referente a duas entidades Usuário e CartaoCreditoUsuario, conforme o seguinte cenário abaixo. Durante ação do automapper na minha ViewModel, não está mapeando a entidade **CartaoCreditoUsuario** referente as suas propriedades existe UsuarioAtivosViewModel.

**Dominio - Usuario**

```
public class Usuario
{
    public Usuario()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        CartaoCreditoUsuario = new List<CartaoCreditoUsuario.CartaoCreditoUsuario>();
    }
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Email{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CartaoCreditoUsuario.CartaoCreditoUsuario> CartaoCreditoUsuario { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Dominio - CartaoCreditoUsuario**

```
public class CartaoCreditoUsuario 
{
    public CartaoCreditoUsuario()
    {
        CartaoCreditoId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CartaoCreditoId { get; set; }
    public bool Aura { get; set; }
    public bool Elo { get; set; }
    public bool Hipercard { get; set; }
    public bool MasterCard { get; set; }
    public bool Visa { get; set; }
    public bool AmericanExpress { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario.Usuario Usuario { get; set; }        
}
```

**ViewModel - CartaoCreditoUsuarioAtivosViewModel**

```
public class CartaoCreditoUsuarioAtivosViewModel
{
    public bool Aura { get; set; }
    public bool Elo { get; set; }
    public bool Hipercard { get; set; }
    public bool MasterCard { get; set; }
    public bool Visa { get; set; }
    public bool AmericanExpress { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel - UsuarioAtivosViewModel**

```
public class UsuarioAtivosViewModel
{

    public UsuarioAtivosViewModel()
    {
        CartaoCreditoUsuario = new List<CartaoCreditoUsuarioAtivosViewModel>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public  string Email { get; set; }

    public  ICollection<CartaoCreditoUsuarioAtivosViewModel> CartaoCreditoUsuario { get; set; } 
...   
}
```

**DomainToViewModelMappingProfile**

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
{

  protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Usuario, UsuarioViewModel>();
        CreateMap<Endereco, EnderecoViewModel>();           
        CreateMap<Usuario, RegisterViewModel>();
        CreateMap<Endereco, RegisterViewModel>();
        CreateMap<Usuario, UsuarioAtivosViewModel>();
        CreateMap<AtendimentoUsuario, RegisterViewModel>();
        CreateMap<LocalAtendimentoUsuario, RegisterViewModel>();
        CreateMap<CartaoCreditoUsuario, RegisterViewModel>();
        CreateMap<CartaoCreditoUsuario, CartaoCreditoUsuarioAtivosViewModel>();
        CreateMap<CartaoCreditoUsuario, UsuarioAtivosViewModel>();
    ...
    }


public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
{
     protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<UsuarioViewModel, Usuario>();
        CreateMap<EnderecoViewModel, Endereco>();      
        CreateMap<RegisterViewModel, Usuario>();
        CreateMap<RegisterViewModel, Endereco>();
        CreateMap<UsuarioAtivosViewModel, Usuario>();
        CreateMap<UsuarioAtivosViewModel, CartaoCreditoUsuario>();
        CreateMap<RegisterViewModel, AtendimentoUsuario>();
        CreateMap<RegisterViewModel, CartaoCreditoUsuario>();
        CreateMap<RegisterViewModel, LocalAtendimentoUsuario>();
        CreateMap<CartaoCreditoUsuarioAtivosViewModel, CartaoCreditoUsuario>();
        ...
    }
}
```

Conforme imagem abaixo, tenho o seguinte retorno do meu contexto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De acordo com as imagens acima, meu retorno esta de acordo com o esperado, contudo, no momento que eu acesso na minha view a propriedade de coleção CartaoCreditoUsuario, é apresentada uma exceção devido ao meu objeto está nulo, pois o mesmo não mapeou de acordo com as demais propriedade da minha viewmodel, conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria se possível uma ajuda dos colega com esse problema.

Dese já agradeço antecipadamente.

Comment: Há algum motivo específico para você usar AutoMapper? A meu ver, a classe de *Model* e *ViewModel* são idênticas.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta desde já. Sim. Minha ViewModel contem dados diferente da domínio. Outra situação que meus DataAnnotations não são utilizados no domínio e sim em outra camada na minha solution como outras particularidades. Te agradeço novamente pela resposta.

Comment: E por que as anotações de atributos não estão no *Model* nem em *ViewModel*, e sim numa terceira camada? Não há necessidade disso. Creio que isso seja o principal problema de sua aplicação não estar funcionando. Se eu direcionar uma resposta, vai ser no sentido de abandonar o DDD, o AutoMapper e essa estratificação de camadas que só atrapalha. Gostaria da resposta assim mesmo?

Comment: Como está o seu controller que passar os dados para View?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez obrigado pela resposta, contudo não irei abandonar a estrategia DDD.

Comment: @EdvaldoFarias segue minha  ActionResult 

        [Route("listar")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_UsuarioAppService.ObterTodos());
        }

Comment: Então você precisa fazer o mapeamento no controller dessa forma: Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Usuario>, IEnumerable<UsuarioViewModel>>(_usuarioApp.GetAll()); - Se não você não estará fazendo o mapeamento, dessa forma o controller sabe que é para fazer o mapeamento naquele momento o que você fazer na classe do auto mapper e pré mapeamento.

Comment: A mensagem de erro não tem a ver com seu objeto estar nulo. Simplesmente o erro diz que sua classe `UsuarioAtivosViewModel` não contém uma property `LocalAtendimentoUsuario`, e de fato no seu código de exemplo (apesar de eu imaginar que você não colocou tudo, somente o mínimo necessário), não tem de fato uma property chamada `LocalAtendimentoUsuario`. O nome da sua collection de `CartaoCreditoUsuarioAtivosViewModel` se chama `CartaoCreditoUsuario `, e não `LocalAtendimentoUsuario`. Corrija sua view e tente novamente.

Comment: @BrunoLeite, resolvou o problema ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olhando rapidinho nas imagens que postou, vejo o seguinte problema:

Seu `Model` da view é um `IEnumerable<UsuarioAtivosViewModel>`. Obviamente, um `IEnumerable<T>` não tem um propriedade chamada `LocalAtendimentoUsuario`.

Supondo que corrige isso (e.g. `@Model UsuarioAtivosViewModel`), seu código indica que esse view model também não tem um propriedade chamada `LocalAtendimentoUsuario`.

Creio que é por causa desses inconsistências que está te dando o erro.

(claro que, sendo essa resposta um ano depois, acho que agora tem nada a ver)